# "Failed to connect to the bus" when opening Google Chrome in Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run Google Chrome on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2). My Linux distribution is Ubuntu 22.04.1. I downloaded Google Chrome by following Microsoft's tutorial on how to run Linux GUI apps on the WSL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).

However, when I launch Google Chrome, I get a series of error messages in my terminal (note that Google Chrome opens) and my command prompt disappears as long as Google Chrome is open (it comes back when I close Google Chrome).

```
[18530:18530:0410/114504.620438:ERROR:browser_dm_token_storage_linux.cc(100)] Error: /etc/machine-id contains 0 characters (32 were expected).

[18530:18556:0410/114504.704485:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18556:0410/114504.704593:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18556:0410/114504.725953:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18556:0410/114504.726029:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18556:0410/114504.781654:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18556:0410/114504.781726:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[18530:18627:0410/114504.885283:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[18530:18627:0410/114504.885697:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[18530:18627:0410/114504.886029:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[18571:18571:0410/114505.084161:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(49)] dri3 extension not supported.
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install dbus
```

But, I am still getting the exact same error messages.

I also tried another command that I found online but which I don't remember. This command caused the error messages about "org.freedesktop.UPower" as seen in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently learning front-end development and I am new to Ubuntu and WSL.

Thank you